# How to create expression array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my js code.

```
 $scope.booking= function(docid,addid){
        console.log(addid);
        $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:81/DoctorStayServiceAngular/model/getDoctorBookingDetail.php",
                params:{"doctorid":docid,"addressid":addid,"day":weekday[d.getDay()]}
                //params:{"doctorid":docid}
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                //$scope.count= response.data;
                i++;
                $scope.count= i;
                //console.clear();
        });

    };
```

and This is HTML.

```
<div id="DocAppoinment" class="col-sm-3" ng-init="booking(x.profileid,x.addressid)">
     <span  ng-bind="count"></span>
</div>
```

And This is my output

[image: My outout]

js function will give me 10 list,and i want to display 1 to 10 on right hand side, as you can see in output it's getting overwritten for obvious reason.

so what should do to print 1 to 10 on right hand side? is there expression array or something in angular? any suggestion?

**PS: I am new to this framework.**

Comment: Is all of this within an `ng-repeat` directive where `x` is each value?

Comment: Besides being new to the framework, you also appear to new to the asynchronous nature of AJAX

Comment: @AaronRussell yes you are right.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty no i am aware on  asynchronous nature of AJAX.

Comment: You can always do `ng-repeat="x in exxes track by $index"` and use `{{$index+1}}` to display the number.

Comment: two way binding will always result `count` to last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a solid solution but one way would be to take advantage of `track-by` in your `ng-repeat` .

example:
`ng-repeat="x in exxes track by $index"` and use `{{$index+1}}` to display the number in your html.

So it would look like

```
<div ng-repeat="x in exs track by $index">
   <div id="DocAppoinment" class="col-sm-3" ng-init="booking(x.profileid,x.addressid)">
        <span  ng-bind="count">{{$index + 1}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use **ng-repeat** directive

ng-repeat uses

`$index,$first,$middle,$last`

$index is a way to show which iteration of a loop you’re in.
for e.g.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in response">
<div id="DocAppoinment" class="col-sm-3" ng-init="booking(x.profileid,x.addressid)">
    <span  ng-bind="count">{{$index + 1}}</span>
</div>
</div>
```